# return и переменные в python3(Вопрос чуть сложнее чем кажется)

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции, условия

как мне это решить?
Есть цикл, в начале он запускает функцию(из другого скрипта)

```
def upr(level):
    up = ""
    right = ""
    if level == debug_zone_1:
        up = 18
        right = 1
    elif level == debug_zone_2:
        up = 30
        right = 1
    else:
        pass
    return up, right
```

По идее он должен вернуть в цикл переменные up и right но условие ниже

```
if pos >= up:
```

Свято уверяет меня в том что переменная up не объявлена:

```
  File "C:\Py\Cube\debug.py", line 100, in <module>
  if pos >= up:
  NameError: name 'up' is not defined
```

Comment: Можно увидеть вызов функции и присваивание переменных?

Comment: https://dropmefiles.com/GnsyQ

Comment: Функция возвращает не переменные (имена), а просто два значения. Вам эти значения нужно принять и положить в другие переменные.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не требуется дополнительная переменная, как в предыдущем ответе. Можно оба значения сразу присвоить двум нужным без всяких индексов:

```
a, b = upr(1)
```

Comment: До этого я отметил сообщение выше правильным, но спустя некоторое время я увидел ваше решение(утрирую) в другом месте так что считаю его более верным

Answer (score 2):

Когда вы возвращаете несколько элементов, то у вас возвращается tuple, чтобы ваш код заработал, вам нужно взять индекс, который соответствует каждому возвращённому элементу

```
something = upr(4)
if pos >= something[0]:
   #что-то делает
else: 
   #что-то делаете, если условие не выполнено
```

Если вы хотите использовать переменные up и right:

```
up = something[0]
right = something[1]
if pos >= up:
   #.....
else:
   #.....
```

Comment: И тут мои 34 переменные переглянулись....

Comment: А кому сейчас легко?

Comment: some = upr(2)
NameError: name 'upr' is not defined

Comment: Так, upr у нас находится в каком-то в классе? Если да, то some = ClassName.upr(2)

Comment: Я так сопьюсь...

Comment: Ничего - ничего, все мы здесь учимся

Comment: Кстати, вы можете использовать глобальные переменные global right и т.д., но лучше так не делать

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96160/discussion-between-terrorka-and-jackwolf).

Comment: up = levels.upr [0] 
TypeError: объект 'function' не может быть подписан

Comment: Почти, up = level.upr(значение, которое вы передаёте)[0]